# How can I use the Second Derivative test to find Maxima and Minima in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I'm looking to create a function that takes an equation and marks the maxima and/or minima, and asymptotes on a graph.

From Calc 1, I remember using the Second Derivative Test.

I started by solving for the roots of the first derivative - but am not sure how I can plot where the point in this vector intersect my original equation.

```Matlab
syms x;         %// 
f = sin(x)      %// Define equation as a function
df=diff(f)      %// First derivatives
ddf=diff(df)    %// Second Derivatives
```

I found the roots for the x-values of these points with `dfRoots = solve(df)`

and then created a vector of them called `dfRoots_realDouble`

```Matlab
dfRoots_double = double(dfRoots);
dfRoots_realDouble = real(dfRoots_double);
```

`dfRoots_realDouble` represent the x-values i need, but I dont know how to plot them as points and separate minima from maxima, etc

I'd like to be able to put in any function, like `sin(6*(x^5) + 7*(x^3)+8*(x^2))` on `[-1,1]` and it highlight all the maxima with one marker, and all the minima with another.

Comment: So this is really a question about plotting rather than anything to do with "Using the Second Derivative test to find Maxima and Minima" as your title states? I suggest simplifying and removing stuff that is not relevant to your actual issue. And if you look at the returned values from your `ezplot` calls you should see a `'Marker'` property.

Comment: I rephrased my question and removed the code for creating the plots

Comment: I see some examples where they've used `'marker'` to plot a points with a certain spacing, but not where their values are equal to those stored in arrays, vectors, or even intercepts.

Answer (score 0):

If you sort the roots, you will have an alternating vector of maximums and minimums.  Use the second derivative to determine if your vector of roots starts with a maximum or a minimum and then split the vector.

```
roots = sort([-3 4 2 -5]);
is_max = (subs(ddf, x, roots(1)) < 0)
if is_max
    max_points = roots(1:2:end)
    min_points = roots(2:2:end)
else
    max_points = roots(2:2:end)
    min_points = roots(1:2:end)   
end
% plot with two different symbols
plot(max_points, subs(f, x, max_points), 'or',...
     min_points, subs(f, x, min_points), '*k')
```